# Calling storedprocedure in SSIS Package with Input Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am invoking a Storedprocedure from SSIS Package. This storedprocedure has three input parameters like Start Date, End Date and a String Variable.

We are calling the SSIS Package from .Net Application. So, we have to pass paramters from C# Code to SSIS Package which in turn passes to Storedprocedure.

I am looking for articles and coders to suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. You can declare variables in SSIS package and set the stored procedure to use them as input variables. Then, pass values to variables from C#.

Here is an example:

In this scenario, I am inserting state and country into a table by passing values from C#.

1. On the SSIS package, create three parameters `StoredProcedure`, `Country` and `State`.
2. Assign the value `EXEC dbo.InsertData @Country, @State` to the variable `StoredProcedure`. Refer screenshot #**1**.
3. Drag and drop a Execute SQL Task on to the Control Flow tab.
4. On the *Execute SQL Task Editor*, configure it to use an **ADO.NET** connection.
5. Change **SQLSourceType** to `Variable`.
6. Assign `User::StoredProcedure` to **SourceVariable**. Refer screenshot #**2**.
7. Refer screenshot #**3** to see how Parameter Mapping section is configured.
8. In C#, you can pass the parameter values as shown below. This code requires reference to DLL `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS`.
9. Screenshot #**4** shows the data inserted into the table.

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace CS.ExecuteSSIS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();

            Package package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\Learn\SSIS\Learn.SSIS\Learn.SSIS\CallFromCS.dtsx", null);
            Variables vars = package.Variables;
            vars["Country"].Value = "US";
            vars["State"].Value = "California";

            DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();

            Console.WriteLine("Package Execution results: {0}", result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Stored Procedure **dbo.InsertData:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData]
(
        @Country    NVARCHAR(50)
    ,   @State      NVARCHAR(50)        
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SSISUsingCS (Country, State) VALUES(@Country, @State)
END
```

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

See info on the [`Application` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms211683.aspx) and the [`Package` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.aspx) where the [`Execute(Connections, Variables, IDTSEvents, IDTSLogging, Object)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.execute.aspx) allows passing in parameters.

```
    var app = new Application();
    Package myPackage = app.LoadFromSqlServer("myPackage", "server", "login", "password", null);

    Variables params = myPackage.Variables;
    params["StartDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    params["EndDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    params["StringVariable"].Value = "ooh a string";

    var packageResult = myPackage.Execute(null, params, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Just found this link and trying with this .. http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx